# Hide a large groupbox whilst a smaller groupbox is shown

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide, groupbox

I have two groupboxes, one is quite large and one is quite small. They most both be at the centre of the screen.

The nature of the groupboxen means that the smaller groupbox is considered to be *inside* the larger one, if the smaller one is contained within the larger one.

How do I defeat this nature? Where 2 is the larger and 1 is the smaller, this code does nothing:

```
groupbox1.Show();
```

since

```
groupbox2.Hide();
```

is a given attribute.

Is there a conceivable way of hiding `groupbox2`?

Comment: Add them manualy to your form in your Form_Load event. After you will be able to display each one separately.

Comment: Adding groupbox1 first and then groupbox2. Does that work?

Comment: @mrsrizan I'm afraid not. That's the first thing I tried. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the form designer to sort this.

`groupbox2` had an attribute of `this.groupbox2.Controls.Add(this.groupbox1)`. I commented that out, and added an attribute of `this.Controls.Add(this.groupbox1)` to the form itself. This is a dangerous way of doing it, but is (apparently) the most effective.

Comment: `groupbox1` is child of `groupbox2` because you did so by using designer. Here is a trick: add them near each other, so they don't overlap (and one won't become child of another) and then enter their position in Properties window or move them by using cursor keys.

Comment: @Sinatr I will remember this. For clarification, that would have done little good here because the large box did not leave enough space for the smaller box to be completely free.

Comment: You wrote on designer? In load write *groupbox2.Parent = this;*

Comment: Add 2 small boxes, move both, resize after. =D

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I tried that, I got a conflict between load and designer. I think because of the way I created the boxes.

Comment: @Sinatr Yep... if I hadn't already made all my controls, like the silly fool I am.

Comment: @Wolfish Leave the designer as it was before! Then add the code

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I usually would. To this end, the modification has worked, and I'm happy with the way I did it.